# Create nested Object from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of objects

```
const sorted = [
{
IsoCode: "EUR",
Buy: 1.948,
Sell: 1.963
},
{
IsoCode: "GBP",
Buy: 2.1184,
Sell: 2.1894
},
{
IsoCode: "USD",
Buy: 1.5781,
Sell: 1.6484
},
]
```

and I want to create an Object looking like this

```
    {
            USD: 
            {
              buy:1.5781,
              sell:1.6484,
    
            },
            EUR:
            {
              buy:1.948,
              sell:1.963,
            },
            GBP: 
            {
              buy:2.1184,
              sell:2.1894,
            }
          }
```

Currently I'am assigning the values manually, but I don't think this is scalable. I'm looking for more effective approach.

Comment: Have you tried a loop? Please post your current code as well.

Comment: I suggest you use `reduce()`.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for `Object.fromEntries` and the object rest syntax:

```js
const sorted = [{IsoCode: "EUR",Buy: 1.948,Sell: 1.963},{IsoCode: "GBP",Buy: 2.1184,Sell: 2.1894},{IsoCode: "USD",Buy: 1.5781,Sell: 1.6484},];

let res = Object.fromEntries(sorted.map(({IsoCode, ...rest}) => [IsoCode, rest]));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
const sorted = [{
    IsoCode: "EUR",
    Buy: 1.948,
    Sell: 1.963
  }, {
    IsoCode: "GBP",
    Buy: 2.1184,
    Sell: 2.1894
  }, {
    IsoCode: "USD",
    Buy: 1.5781,
    Sell: 1.6484
  },
]

const obj = sorted.reduce(
  (acc, { IsoCode, Buy, Sell }) => 
    (acc[IsoCode] = { Buy, Sell }) && acc,
  {}
);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: What's that IIFE good for? Also `arr` is not an array.

Comment: It's to extract needed properties

Comment: But why not just destrucure the `cur` parameter to the reducer directly? `(acc, {IsoCode, Buy, Sell}) => { acc[IsoCode] = {Buy, Sell}; return acc; }`

Comment: Something like this might be better:`sorted.reduce((acc, { IsoCode, ...rest }) => ({ ...acc, [IsoCode]: rest }),{})`

Comment: It just depends whether OP wants to extract these exact keys or the rest, which is not precised. Also, having a pure function instead of mutating the accumulator is just one's opinion.